# What can I do if explorer.exe periodically reboots after installing Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

Yesterday, I installed Windows 10 on a 3-4 year old Dell PC. Today, I booted it up, and discovered an issue: periodically, explorer.exe crashes, hangs, and reboots itself to recover.

This means that about every minute, both File Explorer (though that's not all that's affected, or there would be some other posts around that answered this) *and* the desktop and taskbar freeze, until the process reboots to recover the situation.

On the advice of a forum thread somewhere, I've run `SFC /SCANNOW`, which has turned up nothing:

> Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

I've also had a look around the Net and Super User, and found nothing about this. There are a number of references to an update released in August '15 that did something similar, but that's not the issue I've got and the solutions proposed don't work.

What solutions are there for this issue?

Comment: create a crash dump and share it: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU

Comment: @magicandre1981 Forgive me if I'm not entirely willing to install a reg file from an unknown source.

Comment: it is a textfile, so that you can review it. I also poste the link to the MSDN documentation of the settings that I change

Comment: @magicandre1981 Right-o. Let me have a look. At the same time, Moab's suggestion appears to be working for now, so I might not need it in the end anyway. Thanks for your help, though.